# camel upgrade issue in spring project

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am facing issue in upgrading camel 3.7.0 to 3.15.0. I am getting below error:

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.camel.spring.xml.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.camel.spring.xml.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler
2875Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [producer-camel-core-context.xml];

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the stacktrace  is complete?

Answer (score 0):

**BeanDefinitionStoreException**

If you use ActiveMQ 5.x that ships with Camel 1.x and you upgrade it to use Camel 2.0 you can get an exception while starting.

```
    ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason:
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
    Unrecognized xbean namespace mapping: http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring
```

The reason is basically that the XML namespace changed in Camel 2.0 as explained below.

When Camel went from an activemq subproject to a top level apache project, they changed the URIs for their xml schemas to reflect this in Camel 2.0.

To fix this, in activemq.xml change all occurrences of:

http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring

to

http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring

and

http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd

to

http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd

Refer:
([http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/exception-beandefinitionstoreexception.html](http://people.apache.org/%7Edkulp/camel/exception-beandefinitionstoreexception.html))